# How to prove that changing the equality constraints does not affect the sign of the optimal value of the objective function?

Tags: optimization, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices

Given **random** **Hermitian** matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$，they satisfy：

$$
\text{tr}(A_i)\in[0,1],\quad i=1,2,3,4.\quad \text{tr}(A_1+A_2)=\text{tr}(A_3+A_4)=1
$$

Given **Hermitian** variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$, consider the following **positive semi-definite programming** problem:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{X_i}\quad&\text{tr}\sum_{i=1}^4A_iX_i \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad &X_1+X_3\succeq0,X_1+X_4\succeq0,X_2+X_3\succeq0,X_2+X_4\succeq0\\
&\text{tr}\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i=k
\end{aligned}
$$

How to prove that when I arbitrarily change the value of $k$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$, there always exists $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$, such that the **sign** of the optimal value of the objective function will not change.

**Note:** All $A_i$ and $X_i$ are **square** matrices.

---

**Edit:**  From the first and last inequality constraints we get:

$$
\sum_i X_i\succeq 0
$$

This shows that $\sum_iX_i$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Because we are discussing the sign of the objective function, all $X_i$ here are not zero matrices, otherwise the objective function value will be $0$. So there is $\text{tr}\sum_iX_i>0$, denoted as $k$.

We have previously shown that for any equality constraint $\text{tr}\sum_iX_i=k(k>0)$, the sign of the optimal value of the objective function does not change. And from the inequality constraints we can also deduce this equality. So the equality constraint can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple method of seeing it. Do a change of variables so that $Y_i = X_i / k$. The problem becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{Y_i}\quad& k \,\text{tr}\sum_{i=1}^4A_iY_i \\
\mathrm{s.t.}\quad &Y_1+Y_3\succeq0,Y_1+Y_4\succeq0,Y_2+Y_3\succeq0,Y_2+Y_4\succeq0\\
&\text{tr}\sum_{i=1}^4 Y_i=1
\end{aligned}
$$

You can prove that this new problem is equivalent to the original problem, in particular they will have the same optimal value. However, in this new form it is clear that $k$ just rescales the objective value by some fixed positive constant and can therefore not affect the sign of the result.

Comment: In fact, when I program to solve this SDP, even if the equality constraints are removed, sometimes the sign of the optimal value of the objective function remains the same. Does this mean that the equality constraint is redundant?

Comment: A priori if you remove the constraint then you could have $k$ negative and this would be able to flip the sign. I don't immediately see why the equality constraint should be redundant.

Comment: I tried to prove it from a mathematical point of view, can you help me to see if my proof is correct?

Comment: It doesn't work, you conclude that one sum is 2 and the other sum is k but this does not imply that the sum of the product of the terms is 2 + k.

Comment: Sorry, there are some mistakes in my proof, I have made corrections.

Comment: ok yes, your proof works now